# Methanol fuel cell anode - why not oxygen instead of water?

Tags: electrochemistry

The methanol fuel cell:

\begin{align}
\text{Overall}&:& \ce{CH3OH + 3/2 O2 &-> 2H2O + CO2}\\
\text{Cathode}&:& \ce{O2 + 4H^+ + 4e^- &-> 2H2O}\\
\text{Anode}  &:& \ce{CH3OH + H2O &-> CO2 + 6H^+ + 6e^-}
\end{align}

All the equations balance and still work in theory if the methanol reacts with oxygen at the anode instead of water:

$$\text{Anode}: \ce{CH3OH + 1/2 O2 -> CO2 + 4H^+ + 4e^-}$$

So why is the first anode equation (with water) the correct one? How would a student know to use water at the anode and not oxygen?

Comment: In case of the last reaction at anode, what would get reduced at the cathode?

Comment: As the net electrode reaction, there is not ongoing oxidation AND reduction at the same time.

Comment: What will be the equation if pure methanol without water is used at the anode ?

Comment: How do you know if reaction X takes place instead of reaction Y a priori? You don't.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is rather simple. A student is not supposed to know beforehand. The anode and cathode reaction will depend *on what is being fed to the anode and cathode compartments* in a fuel cell. In the anode section, the only components which are injected there are methanol + water along. Oxidation has to occur at the anode-*by definition*. If water and methanol are present, under those circumtances, methanol gets oxidized to carbon dioxide.

Comment: And what happens if pure methanol, without water, is used at the anode ?

Comment: Who will provide protons for the proton exchange membranes if water is not there? MeOH cannot provide protons.

Comment: So what happens if pure methanol, without water, is used at the anode ? Nothing ? No production of electricity ?

Comment: The success of a galvanic cell is dependent on the rate of electrode reactions. I think water helps there too.

Comment: Why don't you answer my question ? I'll repeat it for the fourth time. What happens if pure methanol, without water, is used at the anode ? Will it be a non-cell ? Will it be some electricity created ? Is water essential ?

Comment: The answer is right there in the comments. You need protons for the membranes to work and provide low resistance. High resistance means low voltage. I *do not* know what happens when pure MeOH is used.

Comment: Maurice  I have answered your question please read my answer above

Answer (score 1):

The student is supposed to use the chemical principles they've learned and come up with reasonable answers.  A [redox, really any] reaction separated into its oxidation and and reduction moieties can possibly be used in a cell or fuel cell. The question was to separate the oxidation and reduction half reactions.
Overall: CH3OH + 3/2O2 = CO2 + 2H2O nicely balanced!
Reduction is easy: 3/2O2 + 6e- = 3O= This is the cathode and a source of H+ is needed to neutralize the oxide ion the logical source is H2O altho I don't know if a weak acid could be used.
The cathode reaction:  3/2O2 + 3H2O + 6e- = 6OH-
The oxidation reaction is a bit trickier; I will break it into simple steps!
CH3OH = C+4 + 4H+ + O= +6e-; what a mess! = CO+2 + 4H+ + 6e- The problem is now evident! There are just not enough O= ions to go around.  A source of O= ions is needed. H2O is a source of oxide ions; O2 is NOT a source of oxide ions. The anode reaction is: CH3OH + H2O = CO2 + 6H+ + 6e-. [The next project is to get the H+ and OH- ions together and possibly capture that energy.]
Please don't get all literal and object that O= and C+4 ions don't exist. The trick is to make the reactions as electrical as possible and keep the oxidation and reduction separate, then try to work out the chemistry; thinking about it outside the box might even elicit some fruitful ideas.

Comment: BTW It took me about 2 hours to come up with this. It can be a slow process. My point is to be patient and to work things out until they make sense.